# I want to subtract the previous non blank cell in the same column

Tags: excel, vba, nonblank

To simplify this, I am computing transmission frequency (in Hertz) for data on a bus.  I need to compute frequency of transmission for each data item. For example, for each value in column B, I have a corresponding time in column A.  I find a value (my current position in column B), find the previous value (also in B), subtract the times in column A corresponding to both.

If I can just calculate the last non blank column cell in the column B (relative to my current position), then transpose to my column of corresponding times, I will be good to go. The last non-blank cell in B is the kicker for me.

I have scoured the web, used a lot of examples, and been able to return a lot of things, but not the value I want.

Comment: `XLookup` can search up

Comment: Post few sample data then show what you want. There are some tricks to find non blank items in Excel.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the colA & colB values starts at A1 n B1. Put :

`=IF(B2="",C1+1,0)` in C2

and

`=IF(B2="","",A2-OFFSET(A2,-C1-1,0))` in D2

and drag downwards. That should do.

hint: count empty cells in colB, reset at each B value. Use the count to 'guide' the subtraction.

pls share if it works/not/understandable.

Comment: It does not seem to work -- not getting it to find or compute correct numbers

Comment: First of all - thank you to everyone.  I have this working.  I think large table the only value that will stay consistent and not be cut or pasted elsewhere is Column F.

Comment: "Assuming that the colA & colB values starts at A1 n B1" <<-- I assumed this.. is ur colA & colB values starts here too? (if it doesn't u'll need to adjust the formula accordingly.)

Comment: First of all -  Thank you to everyone.  Ignore the Col F comment above. -- I just simplified it -- sorry for the early comment - hit by accident and could not edit.  I have this working.  For this example, we have a large table -- the only value that will stay consistent is Column A (timestamp).  I am looking at a transmission in column B.  I am using column C and D for my computations with my answer in column D.   This returns my answer in seconds or milliseconds and then I simply convert that to the units I want.
Column C
=IF(B2<>"",$A2,C1)
Column D
=IF(C2<>C1,C2-C1,"")

Comment: Now if that can be simplified and made not so ugly would love to hear it but am satisfied.